# How to render database records to HTML using Flask?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, webserver

I have run into a problem whereby my db file created through Python doesn't give an error but also doesn't render to a web page.

The database is created in a Python file which I have confirmed does work and the db file is created successfully. The Flask server works just fine and when booted and I navigate to the account page the navigation works but I just get a blank screen below my header and no database printed on the page as it should be.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, g
import sqlite3

DATABASE = 'account_info.db'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)


def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])


@app.route("/")

def render_static():

    return render_template('splash_page.html')



@app.route("/account")

def account_page():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT * from acc_info')
    Details = [dict(first_name = row[0],
                    last_name = row[1],
                    age = row [2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()

    return render_template('account.html', Details = Details)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

'''

```
<h1>
    {% for counter in Details %}
        First Name: {{ counter.first_name }} <br>
        Last Name: {{ counter.last_name }} <br>
        Age: {{ counter.age }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
</h1>
```

Comment: Do you actually have data in the database?

Comment: first open database in any db viewer to see what you have. Next you can use `print()` to see what you get from database in flask.

Comment: Where is `app.config['DATABASE']` set?

Comment: I managed to find the issue, and now feel dumb, the database was for some reason not populating with data so I had to manually enter the data so the code works, just there was nothing to print.